# Simple switching between multiple monitor configurations

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multiple-monitors

#### Context

I use Ubuntu 11.04 on a laptop.
I have three monitor configurations:

- **Work**: disable laptop monitor, use external 1920 X 1200 monitor
- **Home**: disable laptop monitor, use external 1680 x 1050 monitor
- **Other**: just laptop monitor

I use NVIDIA X Server settings to switch between monitor configurations.

- The ideal situation would be that the monitor configuration could be activated based on what external monitor was plugged into the laptop.
- Another reasonable option would be to have a shortcut key that toggled between the three laptop configurations (or perhaps three shortcut keys, one for each configuration).

#### Question

- How can I more simply switch between monitor configurations?

#### Initial thoughts

- A user asked about automatic switching of monitor configurations on [ubuntu
  forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712863) with some more [suggestions here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1074137)
- I thought there might be some way of using a shortcut key to manipulate the `xorg.conf` file.

Comment: Check out this thread for some clues: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62099/how-can-i-toggle-between-single-and-dual-monitor-setup/106223#106223

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/), it's got some potential. I am still figuring it out but it will definitely do what you described. I don't think auto-switching is a realistic option yet, but Disper with a keyboard shortcut is worth trying out.

Comment: Also, there's autorandr/disper, which can remember disper monitor configurations. I think that's just what you need. https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr

Comment: Additionally, there's a GUI for the script. worked perfectly in Maverick, I'm not sure about the current status in Natty (app-indicator) https://bugs.launchpad.net/disper/+bug/619897

Answer (score 2):

If you're using xorg.conf for your setup, this inelegant, but simple solution has worked for me:

Create a separate configuration file for each setup, which you will put in /etc/X11.  Name them something like this:

- xxorg.conf.work
- xxorg.conf.home
- xxorg.conf.single

(The double exes will prevent the server from spontaneously deleting the files)

Then create three simple shell scripts and put them in /usr/local/bin.  Name them something like:

- display.work
- display.home
- display.single

An example of the contents of one of the files looks like this:

- "#!/bin/sh"
- cp -f /etc/X11/xxorg.conf.work /etc/X11/xorg.conf
- echo "Display is set for WORK"
- echo "You must restart the display manager for settings to take effect."

To use these scripts, assuming you've booted up and are looking at the wrong display--

- Press Ctrl-Alt-F2 to bring up a non-graphical shell.
- log in
- as root, (su or sudo, depending on your system) run the desired script.
- restart your X server

Yes, it's not as nice as plug and play would be, but it's pretty quick and painless nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

As @JE2Tom suggested, Disper was able to do the job.
For those interesed, this is what I did.

- I installed [Disper for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~disper-dev/+archive/ppa)
- I then used `CompizConfig - General - Commands` to create shortcut keys for the two commands that i wanted:

  - `disper -s` activates just the primary monitor
  - `disper -S` activates just the secondary monitor