# Broken screen ubuntu 16.04 external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad, with a broken monitor.  It fell down while it was open.

I tried to connect an external monitor to the laptop with an HDMI cable, but can not get the laptop to switch to the other display.  I've tried pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd>, to no avail.  <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> works, but only increases the volume (I can hear sounds).

Checked this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129524/how-to-switch-display-from-laptop-to-external-monitor), but this didn't help.

It is impossible to tell what applications are open, such as terminal when using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  What can I do now?  Is there anyway to force the laptop to display on the external monitor?

Comment: Which model of lenovo ideapad?

Comment: lenovo ideadpad 700 15isk http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/700-series/700-15-inch/

Comment: If you changed the 
Hotkey Mode
 from 
Enabled
 to 
Disabled
 in the BIOS setup utility, 
you will need to press the Fn key in combination with the appropriate hotkey. F3, F8, F4, F10?

Comment: i did not change anything. f11f12 for screen but for example they dont work. i need to do manuel some gpu drivers thing but i did not. maybe it is like that? f1 mute, f2 upvolume f3down and plane mode etc is working.f10 f4 f8 doesnot work and i cant remember before thyey were working.

Comment: Did you try in combination with the Fn key? Based on a picture I found of an original keyboard, it should be Fn-F10

Comment: yes. normally f2 -f3 volume updown works without fn but i also tried with f10 after i insert extermal. i used vga to hdmi.monitor is vga. i connected then f10 but doesnot work. when i run f3, i can hear volume is uppig.

Comment: There may be a BIOS setting, but without a working screen or an identical laptop I'd say the odds of success are slim. You could try unplugging and re-pluggung the screen at the HDMI connnector (of course it's unknown whether the the HDMI2VGA adapter is causing issues on it's own) HDMI requires a hardware handshake that the VGA monitor can't do and it's unknown whether the adapter is actually accomplishing this.

Comment: ok i did tank you @ElderGeek i pushed vgatta2hdmi very hard towars hdmi port on laptop. it was because of that :) tahnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unplug and re-plug the screen at the HDMI connector. You may just have a bad connection.