# 12.10 Black screen on boot after unplugging external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

Here is my story:
1. I plugged an external VGA monitor to my laptor (Dell Vostro 3550) and configured dual display using System Settings/Displays. Everything worked well
2. I unplugged the external monitor, switched off my laptop and left my office
3. Being at home, when I turn on my laptop I get a blank screen on my LCD display. Ctrl+Alt+F1...F7 doesn't work. I assume that my primary display is still set to the external monitor, but I don't have any external monitor at home. How can I switch back to LCD?

Answer (score 0):

#### A quick and dirty method

1. Boot into recovery
2. Select 'root'
3. Remount root partition as writable

   - mount -o remount,rw /
4. Backup, but remove your xorg.conf

   - mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
5. Reboot

#### Plan ahead

Do some research on [Disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/) and see if it can ease your monitor woes once you've gotten back on your system.  You might find [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42393/simple-switching-between-multiple-monitor-configurations) informative.

Comment: Today I tried plugging back the external monitor - it didn't help, both monitors were black. I have found out that this problem occurs only with 3.5.0.27 kernel. If I boot with the previous 3.5.0.25 kernel, all monitors work fine. Can it have anything to do with xorg.conf?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like your drivers haven't been re-compiled for your new kernel.  Have you installed your gfx drivers manually?  Are you using ATI, nVidia, or Intel?

Comment: I didn't instally any drivers - I'm using the ones shipped with Ubuntu. This laptop has a hybrid graphics. That's what `lspi | grep VGA` gives:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]`
The boot behaviour is unpredictable. Sometimes have to use the old kernel, sometimes everything works fine with the new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 16. Before disconnecting the external monitor, you could go to display settings and manually turn off the external one. Then try to disconnect. Works for me.